# Next-to-leading $1/N$ contributions to Feynman diagrams in large $N$

Tags: feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, mesons, asymptotics, large-n

I want to understand $1/N$ contributions to quark bilinear operators $J(x)$ in large $N$, for instance, operators of the form $q\bar{q}$ or $\bar{q}\gamma^\mu q$. As pointed out by [E. Witten](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(79)90232-3), in the large $N$ limit leading Feynman diagrams are planar diagrams with the minimum number of quark loops. When considering quark bilinears, there is at least one $q\bar{q}$ pair, so the leading diagrams are now the planar ones with only one single quark loop (running in the boundary). Noting that intermediate states are always meson states, he establish that the two-point correlator function have the form
\begin{equation}
    \langle J(q)\, J(-q) \rangle = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{F_n^2}{q^2 - M_n^2}\tag{2/5}
\end{equation}

where $M_n$ is the mass of the $n$-meson and $F_n=\langle 0  | J(q) | n \rangle$ is the matrix element for the current to create the $n$-meson from the vacuum.

I would like to do a similar analysis, but for $1/N$ contributions. To begin with, **what are the next leading Feynman diagrams**? I've been thinking and one type of diagrams might be any leading diagram (planar with one quark loop at the boundary) with one quark loop instead of a gluon loop. This would contribute as $1/N$. However, **are there more type of diagram contributing at this order**?

Considering diagrams with a total contribution $1/N$, apart from the leading ones, **would the expression of the two-point correlator above change in any way?**